# How do you store themes in the database?

Tags: asp.net

I know how to load themes dynamically when they are stored locally. Is it possible to store theses themes in the database yet still apply them programmatically as described in referenced MSDN article?

Also - If you do store them in the filesystem, is it possible to change the path of the App_Themes directory to a different location? Like Amazon S3?

[Apply Themes Programattically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Themes need to be in local files (App_Themes/ThemeName needs to exist). 
There's no concept like ThemeProvider (would be nice, but there's not).
Your stylesheet(s) and skin files need to be there, images etc can be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom development tricks, i can advise you see have the [orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) load themes from db.

Comment: Please, extend your anwser with more details from the link. Link could become obsolete...